# Can I choose difference house card without discard two power tokens?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I have an issues with my play group that When I use this card, Can I choose difference house card without discard two power tokens or discard only one if I have only one power token or dont discard any power token ? 
There 's one player in my group understand that he can either choose to discard two power tokens or not and take "choose difference house card" effect. Is he right ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think the correct way to read this would be:

1. Discard 2 power tokens immediately
2. Discard Aeron Damphair
3. If able, choose a different house card from your hand.

Please note that step 2 can't be completed without step 1. Similarly step 3 can't be executed without steps 1 and 2.

This would mean that your friend is wrong as you have to discard 2 power tokens to even make it to step 3.

You must play a new house card if you have one in your hand and you've discarded your 2 power tokens and Aeron Damphair. The only time you shouldn't play a new house card is if there isn't one in your hand.

The 2 power tokens that need to be discarded also seem non-negotiable to me. If they don't have 2 power tokens to discard, they can't activate this card (unless another card says otherwise, but that's a little off topic).

Comment: I agree that the power tokens are a cost to using the optional ability. You either discard 2 power tokens to use the ability, or you don't. However, once you choose to use the ability, it's not optional to play out another House Card from your hand (as long as you're able to do so).

Comment: That seems logical enough to me. I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you everyone so much. We have an issue with this because we don't use English as major language lol

Comment: @3ORZ You must discard 2 tokens to use this card. You must discard Aeron Damphair. You must play a new House Card if you have one in your hand.